# Show that $Z(XY,XZ,YZ)$ is not irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, ideals

Show that $Z(XY,XZ,YZ)$ is not irreducible.

what I think it is $Z(XY,XZ,YZ)=Z(XY)∩Z(XZ)∩Z(YZ)=(Z(X)∪Z(Y))∩(Z(X)∪Z(Z))∩(Z(Y)∪Z(Z))$

Then I am not sure how to carry on, and what I need to show it is $Z(XY,XZ,YZ)$ is a union of two proper subvarieties.

Can anybody help please, thanks a lot.

Comment: It is the union of the three axes.

Comment: @MooS which three? you meant $Z(XY,XZ,YZ)=Z(X)∪Z(Y)∪Z(Z)$? If so, may I ask why?

Comment: $Z(X)$ is not an axis but a plane. $Z(X,Y)$ is an axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that this is equal to the union of the three coordinate axes: $$Z(X, Y) \cup Z(X,Z) \cup Z(Y,Z)$$

Look at the three polynomials $XY, XZ, YZ$. Whenever you have a point on one of the three axes, at least two of the three coordinates equal $0$, which means that all three polynomials evaluate to $0$. If you have a point that is not on any of the axes, then there are at least two non-zero coordinates, and the corresponding polynomial therefore does not evaluate to $0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. can I use set theory to do this $(Z(X)∪Z(Y))∩(Z(X)∪Z(Z))∩(Z(Y)∪Z(Z))=...=Z(X,Y)∪Z(X,Z)∪Z(Y,Z)$?

Comment: For what you want to do there, I'd suggest simply drawing the sets, or show that both are included in the other. Using the algebraic machinery there is unnecessarily complicated.